# Script Sheet : how to fix the time in 12hour (AM/PM) in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

can help how to fix the code in my google sheet > script
when i change the code the `"HH:mm tt"` there use TT to change the (AM/PM) but the code became error..

here the sample error

```
Exception: Invalid argument: MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm tt
CONVERTDATE @ CONVERTDATE.gs:6
```

and my script use here

```
function CONVERTDATE(date) {
  let time = new Date(date);
  let seconds = time.getTime();
  let addHours = 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  let hoursLater = new Date(seconds + addHours);
  let converted = Utilities.formatDate(hoursLater,Session.getTimeZone(), "MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm tt")
  return converted;
}
```

hope anyone here can help me for fix this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`tt` changed to `a`

```
function CONVERTDATE(date) {
  let time = new Date(date);
  let seconds = time.getTime();
  let addHours = 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  let hoursLater = new Date(seconds + addHours);        
  let converted = Utilities.formatDate(hoursLater,Session.getTimeZone(), "MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm a ")
  return converted;              
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: thanks that works... btw, how to make if column B in a full row insert with automatic date and column C use this script as automatic added in a row when the column B have an the data was try follow this formula but error fetch the convertdate, ```=ArrayFormula(if(B2:B<>"",row(B2:B),""(CONVERTDATE($B2))))``` thanks